# ABL inserting and displaying table data

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I apologies for this being a very simple question but as a first time user of ABL open edge and im stuck. I have enter values into a table like so

```
METHOD PRIVATE VOID POPULATETABLE ( ):
    DEFINE VARIABLE I AS INTEGER. 
    DO I = 0 TO 100:
    CREATE TEST.

    ASSIGN TEST.CUSTOMER_NAME="SMITH"
    TEST.ORDER_NUMBER=I  
    TEST.ORDER="BOOKS" 
    TEST.COST=45.00  
    TEST.CUSTOMER_NAME = "JACKSON" 
    TEST.ORDER_NUMBER=I 
    TEST.ORDER="PAPER CLIPS"  
    TEST.COST=1.7. 
    ASSIGN TEST.CUSTOMER_NAME="JONES"  
    TEST.ORDER_NUMBER =I 
    TEST.ORDER="PENCILS"
    TEST.COST=2.50
    TEST.CUSTOMER_NAME = "TURNER"
    TEST.ORDER_NUMBER = I  
    TEST.ORDER="PENS"
    TEST.COST=0.7. 
    END.
    END METHOD.
```

and I'm trying to display them using this

```
 FOR EACH TEST:   
        DISPLAY TEST.COST TEST.CUSTOMER_NAME TEST.ORDER TEST.ORDER_NUMBER.
        RETURN.
END.
```

However the result only shows the last row of data entered. can anyone help, I'm even unsure on whether the display function is right or the assign is.

Comment: Fastest way to find out would be to look into datadictionary or even get the count of records in the Test table.  Your assignement statement has the same fields being assigned over and over again, was that intentional? What is the primary key for the table test?

Comment: I don't know what you mean then you say that I'm assigning the same fields over and over again. Should I be entering rows of data in a different way? As that sounds like it could be the source of the problem.

Comment: You have 2 assignment statements to one create statement.  That means you are still working with the same recrod and overriding the previous values.  Each pass of that loop will create only one record with the last values in it (TURNER,,PENS,0.7).  Also what is the primary key field of your Test table?

Comment: the primary key is order_number. Do you know how I can avoid the overriding from happening?

Comment: Assign the values only one or create 4 different records instead of one recrod and assign to it 4 times.  It is as if you are declaring a variable and giving it 4 different values, only the last one will be the actual value held by the variable. Where are you displaying the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "return" in your FOR EACH is causing the code to leave the loop after the first record. Delete that statement and you'll see all the records.

```
FOR EACH TEST:
DISPLAY TEST.COST 
        TEST.CUSTOMER_NAME 
        TEST.ORDER 
        TEST.ORDER_NUMBER. 
RETURN.   /* this is why you're only seeing one record -  */
          /* get rid of this and you'll see all the records */
END.
```

Comment: The issue with multiple ASSIGNs per CREATE is also messing him up.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid assigning an order# of 0.  It's just asking to confuse people.

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.

do i = 1 to 100:

  create test.

  assign
    test.order_number = i
    test.customer     = "smith"             /* you need some way to get   */
    test.order        = "books"             /* actual data for the rest   */
    test.cost         = random( 10, 100)    /* of the fields...           */
  .

end.
```

And then review the orders with:

```
for each test no-lock:
  display test.
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, all I needed was a create statement per each assign for each record and that worked. Thanks everyone, the working coded looks like:

```
 CREATE TEST.

ASSIGN TEST.CUSTOMER_NAME="SMITH"
TEST.ORDER_NUMBER=I  
TEST.ORDER="BOOKS" 
TEST.COST=45.00.  
CREATE TEST.
ASSIGN  TEST.CUSTOMER_NAME = "TAYLOR" 
TEST.ORDER_NUMBER=I 
TEST.ORDER="PAPER CLIPS"  
TEST.COST=1.7.
CREATE TEST.
ASSIGN TEST.CUSTOMER_NAME="THOMPSON"  
TEST.ORDER_NUMBER =I 
TEST.ORDER="PENCILS"
TEST.COST=2.50.
CREATE TEST.
ASSIGN TEST.CUSTOMER_NAME = "TURNER"
TEST.ORDER_NUMBER = 2 
TEST.ORDER="PENS"
TEST.COST=0.7.
```

FOR EACH TEST WHERE TEST.COST > 1.3 BY TEST.ORDER_NUMBER: 
  DISPLAY TEST.
  END.